# Testing Event pattern in AWS lambda

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am pretty new to AWS and trying to update VPC security group when an Event is triggered by ELB

my Event pattern is something like below

```
 {
  "userIdentity": {
    "invokedBy": [
      "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
    ]
  },
  "eventSource": [
    "ec2.amazonaws.com"
  ],
  "eventName": [
    "CreateNetworkInterface"
  ]
}
```

and sample event is

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.05",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "Root",
        "principalId": "233000205727",
        "arn": "arn:aws:iam::233000205727:root",
        "accountId": "233000205727",
        "userName": "jmfe",
        "invokedBy": "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "eventTime": "2017-04-15T09:10:30Z",
    "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "CreateNetworkInterface",
    "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com",
    "userAgent": "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com",
    "requestParameters": {
        "subnetId": "subnet-2dbdf874",
        "description": "ELB app/prod-artifactory-b-01-alb/73090a08b6f70469",
        "groupSet": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "groupId": "sg-3a3b9a47"
                }
            ]
        },
        "privateIpAddressesSet": {}
    },
    "responseElements": {
        "networkInterface": {
            "networkInterfaceId": "eni-4ad99293",
            "internalInterfaceId": "interface-4ad99293",
            "subnetId": "subnet-2dbdf874",
            "vpcId": "vpc-876a77e2",
            "availabilityZone": "us-east-1d",
            "description": "ELB app/prod-artifactory-b-01-alb/73090a08b6f70469",
            "ownerId": "233000205727",
            "requesterId": "210368014644",
            "requesterManaged": true,
            "status": "pending",
            "macAddress": "0e:61:f3:36:52:da",
            "privateIpAddress": "10.19.84.120",
            "privateDnsName": "ip-10-19-84-120.ec2.internal",
            "sourceDestCheck": true,
            "groupSet": {
                "items": [
                    {
                        "groupId": "sg-3a3b9a47",
                        "groupName": "prod-artifactory-b-artifactory-01_client_sg"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "attachableToInstanceBySet": {},
            "associableWithElasticIpBySet": {},
            "privateIpAddressesSet": {
                "item": [
                    {
                        "privateIpAddress": "10.19.84.120",
                        "privateDnsName": "ip-10-19-84-120.ec2.internal",
                        "primary": true
                    }
                ]
            },
            "ipv6AddressesSet": {},
            "tagSet": {}
        }
    },
    "requestID": "064477de-13d2-4e9c-b579-b69a2e6c4882",
    "eventID": "0928e0db-89c3-4b33-abd5-62020854599a",
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "recipientAccountId": "233000205727"
}



{
  "userIdentity": { 
        "invokedBy": ["elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"]
    },
"eventSource": ["ec2.amazonaws.com"],
  "eventName": ["CreateNetworkInterface"]
}
```

I have created a rule with the above event pattern and want to call an AWS lambda function , the code is in python 3.6 and its just a simple hello world

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return 'Hello from Lambda  test'
```

When ever I test the lambda function with example event (from AWS console) it always  Shows  'Hello from Lambda test' , I think I am not able to test the event and event pattern matching , I have changes the event and event pattern with garbage values and still the result is always pass, **question is  how to test the event and event pattern and see if the event pattern is working correctly within the rule**

Comment: The sample event doesn't get validated for whether it will trigger the function.  It's assumed that it would, or you wouldn't be using it to test the function.  The sample event is to test whether your code handles the sample event's structure and data correctly.

Comment: So apprantly there is no direct way to test in AWS if an event pattern is matching a sample event?

Comment: Right... Lambda never sees the events that don't match -- these are CloudWatch events, right?  CloudWatch doesn't contact Lambda for non-matching events because non-matching events are never actually generated.